# Clojure recursion through let binding

Tags: recursion, clojure, let

From core.clj, the definition of assoc (trimmed of metadata etc)

```
(def assoc
 (fn assoc
   ([map key val] (. clojure.lang.RT (assoc map key val)))
   ([map key val & kvs]
    (let [ret (assoc map key val)]
      (if kvs
        (if (next kvs)
          (recur ret (first kvs) (second kvs) (nnext kvs))
          (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "assoc expects even no of args...")))
    ret)))))
```

what does the let binding of ret achieve?  Why is it not just:

```
(def assoc
 (fn assoc
   ([map key val] (. clojure.lang.RT (assoc map key val)))
   ([map key val & kvs]
      (if kvs
        (if (next kvs)
          (recur (first kvs) (second kvs) (nnext kvs))
          (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "assoc expects even no of args...")))
    ret))))
```

Rudimentary testing (in ClojureCLR) seemed to indicate the latter works ok, and I can't find any documentation indicating the use of the former.  Any clues?

Thanks,  gary

Comment: You're not binding the correct arguments in the recursion. You're setting `map` to the first key in `kvs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version should fail to compile because not enough arguments are passed to `recur` (four are needed in this case). The `let` exists to bind the result of association of the first pair of key/values passed to the first body (3-arity) as `ret`. In case the second body was invoked by itself earlier using `recur` with `kvs` = `nil` (as a result of calling `nnext` in the `recur` form as the fourth argument) `(if kvs ..)` will fail and `ret` can simply be returned. If there are more `kvs` tailrecursion can happen.

Comment: Thanks.  You are of course correct.  My "testing" wasn't doing what I thought it was (or anything else for that matter! :)